# React state disappearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app that uses the MS Graph API (so it's a bit difficult to post a minimal reproducible example). It has a state variable called `chats` that is designed to hold the result of fetching a list of chats from the graph API. I have to poll the API frequently to get new chats.

I query the `chats` endpoint, build an array of `newChats` and then `setChats`. I then set a  timeout that refreshes the data every 10 seconds (it checks for premature invocation through the `timestamp` property stored in the state). If the component is unmounted, a flag is set, `live` (`useRef`), which stops the refresh process. Each chat object is then rendered by the `Chat` component (not shown).

Here's the code (I've edited by hand here to remove some irrelevant bits around styles and event propagation so it's possible that typo's have crept in -- it compiles and runs in reality).

```js
const Chats = () => {
  const [chats, setChats] = useState({ chats: [], timestamp: 0 });
  const live = useRef(true);

  const fetchChats = () => {
    if (live.current && Date.now() - chats.timestamp < 9000) return;

    fetchData(`${baseBeta}/me/chats`).then(res => {
      if (res.value.length === chats.chats.length) return;
      const chatIds = chats.chats.map(chat => chat.id);
      const newChats = res.value.filter(chat => !chatIds.includes(chat.id));

      if (newChats.length > 0) {
        setChats(c => ({ chats: [...c.chats, ...newChats], timestamp: Date.now() }));
      }
      setTimeout(fetchChats, 10000);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchChats();
    return () => (live.current = false);
  }, [chats]);

  return (
    <div>
      {chats.chats.map(chat => (
        <Chat chat={chat} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The Chat component must also make some async calls for data before it is rendered.

This code works, for a second or two. I see the Chat component rendered on the screen with the correct details (chat member names, avatars, etc.), but almost before it has completed rendering I see the list elements being removed, apparently one at a time, though that could just be the way its rendered -- it could be all at once. The list collapses on the screen, showing that the chat state has been cleared out. I don't know why this is happening.

I've stepped through the code in the debugger and I can see the `newChats` array being populated. I can see the `setChats` call happen. If I put a breakpoint on that line then it is only invoked once and that's the only line that sets that particular state.

So, what's going on? I'm pretty sure React isn't broken. I've used it before without much trouble. What's changed recently is the inclusion of the refresh code. I'm suspicious that the reset is taking away the state. My understanding is that the `fetchChats` method will be rendered every time the `chats` state changes and so should see the current value of the `chats` state. Just in case this wasn't happening, I passed the `chats` state from the `useEffect` like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetchChats(chats);
    return () => (live.current = false);
}, [chats]);
```

With the necessary changes in `fetchChats` to make this work as expected. I get the same result, the `chats` state is lost after a few seconds.

*Edit*

---

Still Broken:
After @Aleks answer my `useEffect` now looks like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let cancel = null;
    let live = true;
    const fetchChats = () => {
      if (Date.now() - chats.timestamp < 9000) return;
      fetchData(`${baseBeta}/me/chats`).then(res => {
        if (res.value.length === chats.chats.length) return;
        const chatIds = chats.chats.map(chat => chat.id);
        const newChats = res.value.filter(chat => chat.chatType === "oneOnOne" && !chatIds.includes(chat.id));

        if (newChats.length > 0 && live) {
          setChats(c => ({ chats: [...c.chats, ...newChats], timestamp: Date.now() }));
        }

        cancel = setTimeout(fetchChats, 10000);
      });
    };
    fetchChats();
    return () => {
      live = false;
      cancel?.();
    };
}, []);
```

The result of this is that the chats are loaded, cleared, and loaded again, repeatedly. This is better, at least they're reloading now, whereas previously they would disappear forever. They are reloaded every 10 seconds, and cleared out almost immediately still.

Eventually, probably due to random timings in the async calls, the entries in the list are duplicated and the 2nd copy starts being removed immediately instead of the first copy.

Comment: I'm side eyeing that settimeout that doesn't have a corresponding clear timeout returned from useeffect. I'm sorta new tho.

Comment: Why `setTimeout` and not `setInterval` for polling?

Comment: `setInterval` is problematic for this usecase. I really want to poll 10 seconds after completing the previous request rather than every 10 seconds. With `setInterval`, if the first request isn't complete (due, say, to network latency) the second run will commence anyway. With `setTimeout` the new task is scheduled only after the previous one is complete. Also, I tried `setInterval` anyway, to see if it helps with the bug, and got exactly the same results.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer try adding `key` prop to `Chat` component. Might fix it.

Comment: @Murli how would I do that?

Comment: `<Chat chat={chat} key={chat.id} />` in `.map`.

Comment: Thanks @Murli, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the problem isn't here at all actually. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing. Maybe its a problem with the Chat component? But, the chat component can't `setChats` so I'm not sure how that would play out.

Comment: Use react dev tools or https://www.npmjs.com/package/@welldone-software/why-did-you-render to debug what's happening with components. You might get some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems. First this
`setTimeout(fetchChats, 10000);` will trigger

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchChats(chats);
    return () => (live.current = false);
}, [chats])
```

You will get 2 fetches one after another.

But the bug you're seeing is because of this

`return () => (live.current = false);`

On second useEffect trigger, clean up function above with run and `live.current` will be forever false from now on.

And as `Nikki9696` said you you need to clear Timeout in clean up function

The easiest fix to this is, probably

```
useEffect(() => {
     let cancel = null;
     let live = true;
     const fetchChats = () => {
    // not needed
    //if ( Date.now() - chats.timestamp < 9000) return;

    fetchData(`${baseBeta}/me/chats`).then(res => {
      //this line is not needed
      //if (res.value.length === chats.chats.length) return;

      // remove all the filtering, it can be done elsewhere where
      // you can access fresh chat state
      //const chatIds = chats.chats.map(chat => chat.id);
      //const newChats = res.value.filter(chat => 
      //!chatIds.includes(chat.id));

      if (res.value?.length > 0&&live) {
        setChats(c => ({ chats: [...c.chats, ...res.value], timestamp: Date.now() }));
        cancel = setTimeout(fetchChats, 10000);
      }
    });
  };
  fetchChats()
    return () => { live=false; if(cancel)window.clearTimeout(cancel) };
  }, []);
```

Edit: typo `cancel?.()`  to  `window.clearTimeout(cancel);`

Comment: I've updated the question with info regarding the first version of your answer. It's still not working, but I'll try the 2nd version now, thanks. The filtering is to avoid duplicates btw, before they are set in the state.

Comment: if you need filtering then you can access previous state like `setChats(c =>{  //filter here c should your previous state// return ({ chats: [...c.chats, ...res.value], timestamp: Date.now() }) });`

Comment: Yeah, can do that, and this is better, having removed the live.current bug, but the original problem still persists; the chats are being deleted as soon as they are entered.

Comment: can you recreate it codesanbox.io? Hard to say what is the problem without seeing more code

Comment: i got a typo, not gonna fix your bug but will stop memory leak, need to change `cancel?.()` to `if(cancel)window.clearTimeout(cancel)`

Comment: Thanks, will have to leave it a few hours though. It's nearly 4am here!

Comment: You need stay strong, 2 cups of expresso and you are good to go for another 2 hours /s

Comment: So, the objects are still being removed from the state as soon as they are added. They are being added because the Chat component is being rendered, then removed again.

Comment: Very likely something (useEffect for exmaple) is listening to chats and overwriting it elsewhere. ` I don't think it has something to do with `setTimeout`, after all chats are being concatenated, not overwritten. Do you want to share github link of the project with me?

Comment: Hi @Aleks -- can't -- it's proprietary (government) :(  I agree that it's not the scheduler. This is the most perplexing bit, nothing else is listening to or changing `chats`. This is the only code that touches it. I thought that it may be a corruption in the `Chat` component, caused by a fault in the rendering code, but I've seen in the debugger that the `chats` array is emptied out and that wouldn't be the case if it were simply a renderer gone wrong.

Comment: Can you recreate Chats and Chat components here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new? Just copy paste the code and instead of `fetchData` do some stub like `const fetchData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve([someFakechats]);
  }, 300);
});`

Comment: Everyone and @Aleks. I have a working solution, but still don't understand why my code didn't work. Thanks for spending time looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have an idea what's happening and how to fix it. I am still not sure why it is behaving like this, so please comment if you understand it better than me.

Basically, for some reason I don't understand, the function `fetchChats` only ever sees the initial state of `chats`. I am making the mistake of filtering my newly fetched list against this state, in which the array is empty.

If I change my useEffect code to do this instead:

```js
setChats(c => {
  return {
    chats: [
      ...c.chats,
      ...res.value.filter(cc => {
        const a = c.chats.map(chat => chat.id);
        return !a.includes(cc.id);
      })
    ],
    timestamp: Date.now()
  };
});
```

Then my filter is passed the current value of the state for `chats` rather than the initial state.

I thought that because the function containing this code is in the function that declares the `chat` state, whenever that state changed the whole function would be rendered with the new value of `chats` making it available to its nested functions. This isn't the case here and I don't understand why.

The solution, to only trust the values of the state that is handed to me during the setState (`setChats`) call, works fine and I'll go with it, but I'd love to know what is wrong with reading the state directly.

Comment: Second argument of `useEffect` (after callback) is dependency array. `useEffect` captures initial values from surrounding context but updated ones only will accessible if added to the dependency array. The problem is when one of the values in the dep. array updated it will cause `useEffect` run again. That's why I removed chats from dep. array, `useEffect` shouldn't depend on the same values it is setting. Gonna trigger endless loop. Therefore chat were stale and filtering shouldn't be done inside `useEffect`, unless it's happening  within setChats. gj

Comment: Ah, ok. My understanding of that array is that it is effectively an event list with the body of the useEffect as the event handler.

Comment: Pretty much. `useEffect` does shallow check of items in array. Primitives by ===, objects by reference. Once current value is not equal to the previous, useEffect is triggered. It is triggered at minimum once if array is empty.